# DOCX Encoding issues

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, zip

I have a PHP script that reads information in from a MySQL Database and puts it into a DOCX file, using a template. In the template, there are placeholders called `<<<variable_name>>>` where `variable_name` is the name of the MySQL field.

DOCX files are Zip archives, so my PHP script uses the ZipArchive library to open up the DOCX and edit the `document.xml` file, replacing the placeholders with the correct data.

This worked fine until today, when I ran into some coding issues. Any non-ANSI characters do not encode properly and make the output DOCX corrupt. MS Word gives the error message "Illegal XML character."

When I unzip the document and open `document.xml` in notepad++, I can see the problematic characters. By going to the encoding menu, and selecting "Encode in ANSI", I can see the characters normally: They are Pound (£) symbols. When N++ is set to "Encode in UTF-8 they appear as a hexadecimal value.

By selecting the N++ option to "Convert to UTF-8", the characters appear OK in UTF-8 and MS Word opens the document perfectly. But I don't want to manually unzip my DOCX archive every time I create something - The whole point of the script is to make generating the document quick and easy.

Obviously I need the PHP script to output the file in UTF-8 to make the '£' characters appear properly.

My code (Partially copied from another question on SO):

```
if (!copy($source, $target))  // make a duplicate so we dont overwrite the template
    print "Could not duplicate template.\n";
$zip = new ZipArchive();
if ($zip->open($target, ZIPARCHIVE::CHECKCONS) !== TRUE)
     print "Source is not a docx.\n";
$content_file = substr($source, -4) == '.odt' ? 'content.xml' : 'word/document.xml';
$file_contents = $zip->getFromName($content_file);

// Code here to process the file, get list of substitutions to make

foreach ($matches[0] as $x => $variable)
{
    $find[$x] = '/' . $matches[0][$x] . '/';
    $replace[$x] = $$matches[1][$x];<br>\n";
}
$file_contents = preg_replace($find, $replace, $file_contents, -1, $count);

$zip->deleteName($content_file);
$zip->addFromString($content_file, $file_contents);
$zip->close();

chmod($target, 0777);
```

I have tried:

```
$file_contents = iconv("Windows-1252", "UTF-8", $file_contents);
```

And:

```
$file_contents_utf8 = utf8_encode($file_contents_utf8);
```

To try to get the PHP script to encode the file in UTF-8.

How can I make the PHP script encode the file into UTF-8 when saving, using the `ZipArchive` library?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use any conversion functions; simply use utf8 everywhere.

Let's check that you really have utf8 -- In PHP, use the `bin2hex()` function, apply it to the string that supposedly contains `£`, you should see `C2A3`, which is the utf8 hex `£`.